# Why Hibernate doesn't create a proxy of Entity objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy, entity, hibernate-mapping

Have you ever thought why Hibernate doesn't create a proxy of Entity objects by default?

In a case of `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` it replaces our collection with `PersistentCollection`.

If we have `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` it provides a proxy of property.

Nevertheless, Hibernate can't load `String` field lazily and even don't attempt to return a proxy of `Entity` instead of the `Entity` object.

Why doesn't Hibernate turn objects that we get from session into proxies?

Comment: Why *should* it? Proxies are expensive.

Comment: To add flexibility to returned objects. For instance - lazy loading of strings. Spring isn't afraid of proxies and proxies a lot of things starting from Configuration, AOP and finishing with implementations of @Lookup classes, replacement non-singletons in singletons with proxies etc...

Comment: Every single example of which is adding useful functionality. Lazy-loading of *individual columns* would be insane in terms of typical overhead compared to just loading the row; that's exactly why join tables *exist*.